# Programatically create Tezos Wallet

Tags: smartpy, wallets, tezos-signer

Hi guys inside my ICO website I want to create on the fly a tezos compliant wallet with the custom tokens for people once they purhcase. Is there a way to programatically create a wallet thanks peeps?

Comment: Have you looked into https://www.walletbeacon.io/, which allows users to connect their existing wallet to your site? Creating single purpose wallets per application is a bad idea and is cumbersome for users to manage

Answer (score 0):

Yes here are some approaches:

**[PyTezos](https://pytezos.org/crypto.html#pytezos.crypto.key.Key.generate)**: You can utilize PyTezos for key generation.

**[ConseilJS](https://cryptonomic.github.io/ConseilJS/#/?id=create-an-empty-tezos-account)** but I haven't seen any update for a while.

**Custom JavaScript Method**: While possible, managing keys yourself, especially with custom code, significantly increases security risks. That said, here's a simple (perhaps naive) way to generate a key in JavaScript:

```
import * as bip39 from 'bip39';
import sodium from 'libsodium-wrappers-sumo';
import base58check from 'bs58check';

public generateSecretKey = async (): Promise<string> => {
  const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic(256);
  const seed = await bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic, '');
  await sodium.ready;
  const keys = sodium.crypto_sign_seed_keypair(
    seed.slice(0, 32),
    'hex'
  );
  return base58check.encode(
    Buffer.from('2bf64e07' + keys.privateKey, 'hex')
  );
};
```

After generating the key, you need to send some mutez to its associated address to activate it.